# How can I stop python input() function to remember my previously pressed keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input, keyboard-events

Basically, I am writing a keyboard practice game where you need to press specific keys to win. At the end, the player inputs their name (for a scoreboard) using input() function.

```
import keyboard

...
print(key_that_needs_to_be_pressed)
keyboard.wait(key)
if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
    ...

print('Game Over\nScore= ' + str(score))
user=input('Player:')
with open('scores.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(user+': ' + str(correct) + ' points\n')
```

And the output is:

```
r
t
space
f
d
b
d
w
Game Over
Score= 8
Player: rt fdbdw
```

Is there any way to get rid of the **rt fdbdw** part when the user needs to enter his name
I tried using os.system('cls') and simulating pressing backspace before `input()` part but none of that works.

Edit:

I've tried flushing the input stream [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520893/how-to-flush-the-input-stream-in-python) but that doesn't work. Other suggestion was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168662/how-clear-stdin-in-python) but I use windows.

Comment: Can you update your question with what exactly you tried? "It didn't work" with no code is not very helpful.